# In iOS16.4 Email inside TextField prompt rendered blue

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode14

After upgrading to Xcode Version 14.3, the TextField prompt in iOS 16.4 is  rendered blue not gray as it was in iOS 16.3

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var email: String = .init()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("account@email.com", text: $email)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this:

```
TextField("\("account@email.com")", text: $email)
```

or this:

```
TextField("", text: $email, prompt: Text(verbatim: "account@email.com"))
```

Comment: That works but it looks unswifty

Comment: you can also use this: `TextField("email address", text: $email)`

Comment: like the last option thank's